# Are Elantrians' kids Elantrian or human?

Tags: cosmere, genetics, elantris

In "The Hope of Elantris", it is revealed at the very end that (major spoilers)

> Raoden impregnated Sarene

so apparently the Elantrians can reproduce. What would the kid look like? Human? Elantrian? Some mix?

**What would the child of two Elantrians look like? I'm looking for either Word of Brandon or good reasoning.**

Comment: [The annotation](https://brandonsanderson.com/annotation-the-hope-of-elantris/) (which is mostly just the same as the postscript in Arcanum Unbounded) only really talks about the inspiration for the story.

Comment: -1 This is blatant case - Galladon told all you need about life of an elantrian child. And if you didn't notice Elantrians are not an inhuman race - it's just some local people enhanced by magic. It's like asking about reproduction of Kinghts Radiant...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

> Question:
>   If two Elantrians had a baby, would he be an Elantrian too?
>
> Brandon Sanderson:
>   What a good question. The answer is no, actually. There's actually a character in the books who's an Elantrian who did become an Elantrian whose parents were connected to Elantris, but that was seen as something that didn't always happen.
>
> [Source](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/34/#e1785)